# Get Class Name Value Using "Starts With" Selector

Tags: jquery, html

For a HTML such as

```
<a href="#" class="a b nl-3522">First</a>
<a href="#" class="a b nl-7352">Second</a>
<a href="#" class="a b nl-4874">Third</a>
<!-- Note that classes nl-* are being added dynamically and are random so I can't 
   hardcode the value -->
<!-- Also, the number of classes can vary for each anchor -->
```

I'm trying to get the value of the class which starts with `nl-`. The following is the event handler that I currently have

```
$('.a').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var $anchor = $(this);
        // how do I use class^="nl-" here so that I get the value nl-3522
        // if I click on "First" or nl-7352 if I click on "Second"...
});
```

Adding the fiddle too to make the job easier to test it live : <kbd>[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/snxhgLf5/)</kbd>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does it by splitting the classes and then matching and is therefore totally **independent on the index of the class:**

```
$('.a').on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var $anchor = $(this);            

            var get = $.grep(this.className.split(" "), function(v, i){
               return v.indexOf('nl-') === 0;
           }).join();

            alert(get);
            // how do I use class^="nl-" here so that I get the value nl-3522
            // if I click on "First" or nl-7352 if I click on "Second"...
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/snxhgLf5/7/

Comment: Great. Will accept it once the system allows me to.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('.a').on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var $anchor = $(this).attr('class').split(" ")[2];            
           alert($anchor)
});
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/snxhgLf5/4/)

Comment: The number of classes can vary. Sometimes there can only be one class. So I can't look at the 3rd index always

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [contains selector *](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) like below

```
$('.a[class*="nl-"]').on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var $anchor = $(this);
            // how do I use class^="nl-" here so that I get the value nl-3522
            // if I click on "First" or nl-7352 if I click on "Second"...
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/snxhgLf5/7/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('.a').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var $anchor = $(this);
        if(($anchor.attr("class")).indexOf("nl-")>=0)
           alert($anchor.attr("class"));
});
```

[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/snxhgLf5/10/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$(":contains('nl-')").on('click', function(e){...
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I was looking for